# Discrete math(Solve for congruence)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is my understanding correct? I am trying to solve the congruence of $x^3-x ≡ 0($mod $3)$ Should I be factoring the left to make it $x(x+1)(x-1)$? Whats the next step after I factor?

[Remark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2kYa.png)

Comment: $a \equiv b$ mod(n) means $a-b$ is divisible by $n$ so, after factoring, if $n\mid  (x-0)$; $n\mid(x-1)$; $n\mid(x+1)$, then the function is congruent. I believe the values of x that apply are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...{$\mathbb{N}$}

Comment: @poetasis Could you please take a look at the screenshot [Remark] in my posting. In my problem the solution should be: x=0(mod3) or x=1(mod3) or x=-1(mod3)  ?

Comment: The bad/long but perfectly acceptable way to do it is to try every value of $x$.  There are only three to try $x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, $x \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, or $x \equiv 2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$.  As $0^3 - 0 = 0 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $x\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ is one answer.  Try the other two... but... that's not a recommended way to do it... except as a learning experience.  As a learning experience I *insist* that you should try each case and see what happens.

Comment: @Surnic Perhaps I don't remember what moduli are about as well as I thought. From my admittedly volatile memory of about 40 years ago, I thought it was a cyclic thing of remainders such as $3 (mod3)=0$, $4(mod3)=1$, $5(mod3)=2$ and so on. If this is/were true, then the values that satisfy $x$ alone would be $3,6,9…$; for $x-1$ the values would be $1,4,7…$; for $x+1$ the values would be $2,5,8…$. Thus, they would include all natural numbers. You could include all integers but I chose not to for no special reason. If I’m off base, you can correct me or ignore me. I won’t distract you again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As $3$ is prime if you have $m\cdot v \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ (assuming $m$ and $v$ are integers) then that means $3|m\cdot v$ and, because $3$ is prime that means either $3|m$ or $3|v$ or in other words, either $m \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ or $v\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

So if $x(x+1)(x-1)\equiv 0\pmod 3$ that means either

1. $x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$
2. $x +1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ which means $x\equiv -1 \pmod 3$
3. $x -1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ which mean $x \equiv 1\pmod 3$.

Notice that those are the only possible for options for $x$ so that means $x^3 - x\equiv 0$ for *EVERY* possible integer $x$!

Another way of thinking this is to note $x-1, x, x+1$ are $3$ consecutive integers.  As every third number is a multiple of $3$ one of these $3$ must be a multiple of $3$.  So $(x-1)x(x+1) = x^3 - x$ is divisible by $3$.

Also note: as a result $x^3 - x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ for all integer $x$ then $x^3 \equiv x \pmod 3$ for all integers $x$.

Indeed if $x\equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $x^3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and if $x\equiv -1 \pmod 3$ then $x^3 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$ and if $x\equiv 1\pmod 3$ then $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

You might be wondering about $2 \pmod 3$.  But $2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$.  And if you don't buy that.  If $x \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ then $x^3 \equiv 8 \pmod 3$ but $8 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.  So $x^3 \equiv x \pmod 3$.